# How does ROS build system work?

Tags: rosmake, cmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have been using ROS for quite sometime and have installed many packages of my own and from the sources available. But i would like to know how the building happens. What rosmake actually does? cmake followed by make? Why is manifest.xml very important. I might have missed a tutorial if available on this. Could someone point to it if available or give some detail about the building process here.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29317/how-does-ros-build-system-work?/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosmake basically calls make recursively.  This answer talks about the difference between rosmake and make: http://answers.ros.org/question/10614/rosmake-vs-make

In rosbuild the Makefile invokes CMake, and uses rospack to get the package information from the manifest.xml files.

And you should read about the manifest.xml on the [wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Manifest)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0